# How to take a string of digits and find out if the digits are increasing?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For this function I am supposed to take in 2 parameters that are both strings. The first parameter is any positive digit and the second is a digit that is supposed to split the other digit into groupings. This is an example of the code:

```
def split_tester(N, d):
    # Your code should include  dosctrings and the body of the function
    if N.isdigit() and d.isdigit():
        N1 = int(N)
        d1 = int(d)
        substring = ""
        new_sub = ""
        retsub = ""
        for i in N:
            substring = substring + i
            if len(substring) == d1:
                new_sub = new_sub +substring+ " "
                substring = ""
        print(new_sub)
```

So in the shell it would print `12 34` when `split_tester("1234","2")`. My question is how can I show that the 34 is greater than the 12 when these are cast as strings and are in the same variable?

Comment: By converting to a value and comparing

Comment: Cast them as numbers with `int()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplifying your function a little bit:

```
def split_tester(N, d):
    d_num= int(d)
    num_list = [int(N[i:i+d_num]) for i in range(0, len(N), d_num)]

    for i in num_list:
        print(i, end=" ")

split_tester("1234", "2")
```

You can perform your desired comparison (if 12 is greater than 34 etc.) on the numbers of the output list: num_list